# Customized loss functions PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a regression problem where I want to penalize more on top of a normal MSELoss if the sign of y_true & y_pred is not the same. I am thinking of something like this:

```
CustomizedLoss(x, y, alpha) = MSELoss(x, y) if sign(x, y) == 1 else alpha * MSELoss(x, y)
```

I read from https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-loss-function-does-not-converge/87514/3 that when using a sign function - it would return a zero gradient that the model would not be able to learn. I want to know whether the customized loss would make sense to begin with.

Comment: The "sign" function is not differentiable but you can use it to assign different weights to exemples of your dataset. It makes sense to customize loss functions

Comment: Additionally, you could just map the signs of y_true and y_pred to 0 or 1, and use cross entropy loss. Your customized loss function can add `MSELoss` + `CrossEntropyLoss` then.

Comment: In particular how can I map the signs then use cross entropy loss? I received the error (with pytorch: IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1) as I do not get the 'possibility' of forecasting into each of the classes?